# I'm trying to use regex to pattern match a line from my input file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, pattern-matching

I have an input file with lines containing 10 columns in the following format:

```
String,Only Integer,Only String,Alpha Numeric,Alpha Numeric of length 7,
Alpha Numeric of length 7(with 1,3,4 as characters and 2,5,6,7 as digits),
Decimal(range from 0.4 to 0.8),Decimal,Only String,Only Integer of length 5
```

All the 10 columns are in the same line. I'm Trying to use the regex pattern to get only columns 7,8,9. I'm trying with this regex. Can someone help please.

```
private static class RegexParser{
   private static final String regex = "(.*),(^[0-9]*$),(^[a-z][A-Z]*$),"
              + "(^[a-z][A-Z][0-9]*$),(^[a-z][A-Z][0-9]{7}*$),"
              + "([a-z][0-9][a-z][a-z][-9][0-9][0-9]{7}*$),([0].[4-8]*$),"
              + "(^[0-9]+(.[0-9][0-9]?)?),(.*),(^[1-9]{5}*$)";
                private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

                private Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("");

                public String parse(String line) {
                    matcher = matcher.reset(line);
                    if (matcher.matches()) {
                        String m = matcher.group(7) + matcher.group(8) + matcher.group(9);
                        return m;
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are your columns comma-separated and will any of the values contain commas?

Comment: How to you differentiate between the columns?

Comment: columns are comma separated and no value contain commas!

Comment: @cvk533 - in that case, doing it regex group matching seems like overkill.  I've posted an answer with a simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

Matching groups in regex seems like overkill for your scenario.  Use a CSV parser, or if the values are all comma-separated and no values contain commas, something as simple as this can probably do the trick.

```
String[] elements = line.split(",");

return elements[7] + elements[8] + elements[9];
```

Comment: what if my first column is not a string?

Comment: Can we 10 if conditions to match all the column requirements?

Comment: The line itself is represented as a String, and the String.split() method will give back an array of Strings.  However, you can create variables of the appropriate type from that String array - e.g. if the first column is an integer, you can do something like this: int value = Integer.valueOf(elements[0]);

Comment: Ok Got it! Can you help with regex for this column Alpha Numeric of length 7(with 1,3,4 as characters and 2,5,6,7 as digits)?

Comment: Use `String[] elements = line.split(",", -1);` to avoid missing empty columns at tail end of the record.